# How to make my customcomponent update/repaint when its data source is changed?

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin

I'm trying to build a custom component in vaadin.The componnent will have a list of objects in a panel,which I fetch them manually by iterating over a BeanItemContainer I have defined.It basically works fine.But now I want to have an adding button which will add a new element in the list every time u click on it.When the adding button is clicked, a window with some fields and a save button will pop up.If u click on the save button in the window,the new Item will be saved to the database.Now I can create a new Item and save it to the container.However,I don't know how to update or refresh the UI(list) so that my new object will show up in the list.Should I add a repaint listener or create a thread which will always repaint the list panel or something else?How can I do it?Thanks for any suggestion or hint.Your kind help is highly appreciated.The following is the code which defines the main composite and the list.

```
public adminComposite(String listType,String objectType,Container source) {
    this.container=source;
    mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    panel = buildPanel(source);
    label =new Label(listType);
    mainLayout.addComponent(label);
    mainLayout.addComponent(panel);
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);


}


private Panel buildPanel(Container c) {
    Panel bpanel = new Panel();
    bpanel.setHeight("400px");
    // verticalLayout_1
    panelLayout = (VerticalLayout)bpanel.getContent();
    //iterate the container to fetch all Items
    for(Iterator i=c.getItemIds().iterator();i.hasNext();){
        //get current Item id,then get a item
        Object id = i.next();
        Item it =c.getItem(id);
        // get data out of the item and fill them into the horizontalLayout
        String caption =(String)(it.getItemProperty("caption").getValue());
        String shortmsg = (String)(it.getItemProperty("sms").getValue());
        Date time = (Date)(it.getItemProperty("timestamp").getValue());
        int uid = (Integer)(it.getItemProperty("uid").getValue());
        HorizontalLayout newline = buildHorizontalLayout(uid,caption,shortmsg,time);
        newline.setSizeFull();
        panelLayout.addComponent(newline);
    }
    add = new Button("Add New");
    add.setDescription("Add a new object in the list and database");

    bpanel.addComponent(add);
    panelLayout.setSpacing(true);
    panelLayout.setMargin(true);
    return bpanel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on tutorial Addressbook application. There is a table and data source container. When button 'New' is pressed, new entry is added to data source container and automatically ItemSetChangeEvent is propagated to the table. Finally, new entry is displayed on the table

You may use the same approach. Implement Container.ItemSetChangeListener in your custom component. In method **buildPanel** register your component as container listener (See AbstractSelect.setContainerDataSource for listener registration example)

Comment: Thx for reply.I managed to settle it with a easy way, I just reinitialize the panel again in the click listener to fetch the new data from the container and reinitialize the UI.The code is like:`save=new Button("Save"); save.addListener(new ClickListener(){panel=buildPanel();mainLayout.addComponent(label);mainLayout.addComponent(panel);});`

Comment: This is quite an ugly solution. ChangeListener is the proper way of solving your problem.

Comment: @user2365727 Thx for your good advice.Excuse me,I have read the Contact List example before in the tutorial. That is much simpler case. And only value change listener is used.I can understand that example.But I don't quite understand when the Interface u infered is implemented, what has really been added in the componnent.For instance,What the ItemsetListener will listen to if I implement the interface?Do u have any example code for that and for that? abstractSelect.setContainerDataSource.Is it easier if I just add a listener to the container and when its Item set change, the UI get repaint?

Comment: @RenatGilmanov I can't agree more.But problem is that I don't quite understand the more complicated listeners implemented as an interface .Do u have some good example code?